# Postgres show command in block of code

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

How can you use the `show` command in block of code?

I tried it several ways,  but all I got was an error

```
do $$
begin
show enable_mergejoin; -- I need to to print this value (on/off)
end $$
```

Comment: Please add a few more details if possible

Comment: Why can't you just use `show enable_mergejoin` without the PL/pgSQL block?

Comment: because I needed to check the settings in a current transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` returns a result. In PL/pgSQL you can't "just" run a statement, the result of a statement must be stored in a variable:

```
do $$
declare
  l_value text;
begin
  show enable_mergejoin into l_value; -- retrieve and store the value
  raise notice '%', l_value; -- print the content
end $$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is using [administrative functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-admin.html) `current_setting` and `set_setting`. These functions access same code as `SHOW` and `SET` commands:

```
do $$
begin
   raise notice '%', current_seting('enable_mergejoin');
end$$
```